# How to run a script in Cocos Creator after game has finished loading?

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

How can I run a `.ts` script in Cocos Creator after game has finished loading? It should be able to get run without having to attach a component to a node in a scene.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a method to a `Game` event which will run after the game has been initiated. This can be done in the global scope.

Here's an example:

```
function doSomeStuff()
{
    console.log('Game has been initiated!');
    // ...
}
cc.game.on(cc.game.EVENT_GAME_INITED, doSomeStuff);
```

If you wish to run something even earlier, before the game scripts have been loaded, use `EVENT_ENGINE_INITED` instead of `EVENT_GAME_INITED`.